# How to combine weka and LibSVM in java code

Tags: java, classification, weka, libsvm, document-classification

I have successfully integrated LibSVM API to mu java code. I need to transfer large document collection to numerical representation and give it to LibSVM classifier. As far as I know weka has the ability to transfer documents to feature vectors. Can any one please tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

U can do it like this

```
    DataSource source = new DataSource(new File("mycsvinputfile"));
    System.out.println(source.getStructure());
    Instances data = source.getDataSet();

    // setting class attribute if the data format does not provide this information
    // For example, the XRFF format saves the class attribute information as well
    if (data.classIndex() == -1)
        data.setClassIndex(data.numAttributes() - 1);

    //initialize svm classifier
    LibSVM svm = new LibSVM();
    svm.buildClassifier(data);
```

Don't forget to use weka.jar, libsvm.jar, and wlsvm.jar (the libsvm wrapper) in your project. So just include all 3 jars in your build path or class path or whatever.

Comment: do we really need wlvsm? If so where I can find it?

Comment: It's a wrapper for libsvm. So u would pretty much need it. Best